# XmlStreamReader in Salesforce How it works?

Tags: salesforce

i am new in SalesForce Commerce Cloud,and i have to work with XmlStreamReader function to read a simple xml file,i just want to know the basics how it works and if someone have some examples i will be more thankful.

Answer (score 0):

PLease refer to the help documentation at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_reader.htm.